# Images are not output to angular via ng For

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

here

I want to output a sequence of images but nothing comes out why ?

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor ="let read of books">
    <a >
    <img src='{{read}}' alt="">
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  books:String[] = [];
  constructor(private bookService:BookService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.books = this.bookService.getAll();
  }

}
```

```
export class BookService {

  constructor() {
  }

  getAll(): String[] {
    return [
      'src/assets/images/books/book-1.jpg',
      'src/assets/images/books/book-1.jpg',
      'src/assets/images/books/book-1.jpg',
    ]
  }
}
```

An empty window is displayed

I changed the paths to the images, I didn't find any more options

Comment: It seems the issue is with the relative URL provided in the books service.

Answer (score 0):

Update your API response by removing src prefix. So, your path would be `assets/images/books/book-1.jpg` because when you start your path from `assets` then it directly pointing to `src` folder.